# Assign function to given Knockout JS component parameter

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, components

Noramly, Knockout JS components, using the [recommended](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html) AMD module pattern, accept parameters:

```
define(['text!./Unlisted.html'], function (html) {   
    var unlistedVM;

    function Unlisted(params) {
        unlistedTeesVM = this;

        this.sProductCode = params.sProductCode || 'gmn';
        this.bIs18 = params.bIs18;
        this.successCallback = params.successCallback;
        this.notificationCallback = function () { null; };
        // ...
        return unlistedTeesVM;
    }
    // ...

    return { viewModel: UnlistedVM, template: html };
});
```

But I want to assign the `notificationCallback` to a function in the Notification component:

```
define(['text!./Notifications.html'], function (htmlString) {
    var notificationsVM;

    function NotificationsVM(params) {
        notificationsVM = this;
        this.sProductCode = params.sProductCode || 'gmn';
        // ...
        this.showNotification = function _showNotification(message) {
        // ...
        }.bind(this);
        // SET PARAMS
        params.notificationCallback = notificationsVM.showNotification;
        // THIS ALSO FAILS
        params.notificationCallback = this.showNotification;
        // ...
        return notificationsVM;
    }

    // ...

    // Return component definition
    return { viewModel: NotificationsVM, template: htmlString };
});
```

The assignment always seems to work if I pause execution on `params.notificationCallback`. Apparently a copy of the `notificationCallback` is passed to the Notification component because the function in the Unlisted component is called instead of the intended showNotification method in the Notification component. Is there a way to assign the `notificationCallback` function of the Notification component to the Unlisted compent's `notificationCallback` own property?

Here is a snippet of the Unlisted component's HTML:

```
<notifications params="sProductCode: sProductCode, notificationCallback: notificationCallback"></notifications>
```

Comment: Can you add code on how you return your component?

Comment: I edited the question to demonstrate the technique to return the components.

Comment: I have since found a solution that does not answer my question. Now I use the Pub/Sub pattern of knockout.js, which uses `ko.subscribable` and `notifySubscribers`.

Comment: Maybe you should not use outer scope variable like `unlistedVM` and `notificationsVM` as it will result to unexpected behavior, you can use `this` explicitly or defined something like `var self = this` inside your `constructor` if you need to access this in a `callback`.